# Android app control ringer volume, not media

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to find the most simple way to have an app control the **ringer volume of the phone** and not even worry about media volume.

I'm building a live wallpaper with a game engine, it's fussy and complicated, but it works. the only issue is while it's running in preview or set at the wallpaper, it **controls media and not ringer**, which is annoying to everyone for obvious reasons.

I've looked a lot for help, for both eclipse and the game engine I'm using and I have come up short.

Any information you have would be great, thank you very much.

Comment: I'll try and post some code shortly, but it's not typical of android apps as it was exported from a game engine.

Comment: I had same problem a while ago. Its Hard to find someone that really understands the problem and even harder to find a solution :(. This plugin is about to be released (http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/172275-Uni2LWP-Create-Live-Wallpapers-with-Unity), I hope they address this issue. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look [Controlling Your App’s Volume and Playback](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/volume-playback.html). I had similar issues and fixed them using `setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);`

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm trying to adjust the ringer volume only, like changing it between vibrate, silence, and different levels of ringer volume, not in call volume.